# Install discord.js on debian

Tags: javascript

I am trying to install `discord.js` to make discord bots i was trying to get it but i can't find a way to get it. All i could find is `npm i discord.js` but i get told `bash: npm unknown command` or something please help. By the way, i tried using `sudo apt-get install discord.js` but it says `unknown package 'discord.js'`.

```
$ npm i discord.js
bash: npm: command not found
$ sudo apt-get install discord.js
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package discord.js
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'discord.js'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'discord.js'
```

Comment: Have you installed node.js on your machine?

Comment: install node.js (usually packaged with npm by default, but you might be required to install npm as well) then just do `npm init` to create a project and `npm i discord.js`

Comment: i already have node.js and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`discord.js` is not a package you can install from the Debian package repositories.

As others have mentioned it is a node.js module and can be installed through npm.
However, it appears you do not have npm installed.

> bash: npm: command not found

It is possible that node.js was installed without npm.
I would recommend that you try installing npm explicitly, then running `npm init` and `npm i discord.js`

Comment: i now have another problem: i was able to get discord.js but when i tried to run, nothing happened even `console.log()` didn't work

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get discord.js installed. Can we see the code you're having problems with now? @chboo1

Comment: Link to my other question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267703/make-node-js-print-outputs)